# What code gets run when you run "rails generate scaffold"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My question is as simple is that: what code (in the Rails codebase) gets run when you run the `rails generate scaffold` command? I don't really know how I'd go about figuring that out.

(P.S. The reason I'm interested in this is because I want to track down what I believe to be an esoteric bug in Rails.)

Comment: You're trying to track down a bug, but you can't track down which code gets run when you execute `rails generate`? How are you going to do one, if you can't do the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this gets you on your way: https://github.com/rails/rails/search?q=scaffold&ref=cmdform